# Перевод формата TIMESTAMP в читаемый вид

Tags: php

Не знаете ли функцию, которая бы переводила 
 TIMESTAMP 2013-06-13 18:15:23 в вид такой, как в Вконтакте. Напримем

Было: 2013-06-13 18:15:23

Надо: 13 июня 18:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать:

```
$date = '2013-02-13 18:15:23';

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU'); // установил локаль
echo strftime("%d %B %H:%M", strtotime($date)); 
setlocale(LC_TIME, $oldLocale); // вернул старую
```

Или самому соорудить что-то вроде этого:

```
$date = '2013-02-13 18:15:23';

function human_date($date)
{
    $months = array('января', 'февраля', /*.. и т.д.*/);

    $date = new DateTime($date);
    $month = $months[$date->format('n')-1];

    return $date->format("d {$month} H:i");
}

echo human_date($date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы распарсил дату функцией date-parse а потом тупо слепил все до кучи. А имена месяцев брал бы из массива.

Примерно так:

```
<?php

function date2vk($timestamp){

    $months=array(
        'января','февраля','марта',
        'апреля','мая','июня',
        'июля','августа','сентября',
        'октября','ноября','декабря'
    );

    $date=date_parse($timestamp);
    return $date['day'].' '.$months[$date['month']-1].' '.$date['hour'].':'.$date['minute'];
}

echo(date2vk('2013-09-1 09:30:23'));
```

Результат выполнения по идее будет:

```
1 сентября 9:30
```

(Писал на коленке, не тестировал)

Если нужно более изящное решение (без использования массива имён) - можно обратить внимание на функцию mktime и связанные с ней.

По теме:

- [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-parse.php)
- [mktime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php)
- [PHP Month Number to Month Name the Easy Way](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/php-month-number-to-month-name-the-easy-way)